# MS Dynamics CRM 2011 Rollup 14 caused Generic SQL Error

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, rollup

We're a new Dynamics CRM shop. We have loaded Accounts, Contacts and Notes from our old system, so there's not much on the system yet. After applying Rollup 14 last night, we log on this morning to a "SQL Server Error" screen.

The same result occurs for all links under "My Work", except Announcements, which appears to be correct (empty, but no SQL error).

The Event Log has the following message:

```
[CrmException: Generic SQL error.]
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.ServiceCommands.PlatformCommand.XrmExecuteInternal()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.ServiceCommands.RetrieveMultipleCommand.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.DashboardSelector.RetrieveDashboard(String logicalName, String[] columns)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.DashboardSelector.AddUserDashboard()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Components.UI.CrmUIControlBase.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

[HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.]
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a related record that's missing as part of your import.

Try using Query Analyzer to determine the SQL statement(s) that cause the exception.  This will usually contain information such as the entity name (table) allowing you to determine what custom code (plugins/workflows) if any is running against that entity or what schema issues may now be occuring.

Answer (score 0):

Reset the IIS and make sure all CRM & SQL the services are running.
If still there is an issue, try to re-install Roll-up 14. Re-installing helped someone to fix different roll-up the issue.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. When uninstalling Update Rollup 14, I received the message...
Action Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Common,Update.DBRemoveAction Failed.
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY
constraint "owner_importlogs". The conflict occurred in database
"CnxDynCRM_MSCRM”, table “dbo.OwnerBase", column OwnerId'.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Apparently, this isn't related to Rollup 14. After reverting to a pre-rollup snapshot, I still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue after I applied update roll up 14. When I looked at SQL, my MSCRM_CRM database was showing 'suspect' next to it which is probably an indication that it is corrupt. luckily I had a back up and I had to delete it and restore the backup and everything is working fine now.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I re-installed update rollup 14 after i fixed the db.